How to Associate Series with Specific Y-Axis in ApexCharts While Retaining Custom Series Names?
I'm working with ApexCharts in a Vue.js application where I need to dynamically link series to specific y-axes based on the series name. However, I've encountered an issue where the series must be named exactly as the seriesName property of the y-axis configuration to ensure proper association. This requirement conflicts with my need to display more descriptive series names in the chart legend and tooltips.
Here's a simplified version of my current setup:
Vue Component:
<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

export default {
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts
    },
    data() {
        return {
            chartOptions: {
                yaxis: [
                    {
                        seriesName: 'Température',
                        // Axis configuration...
                    },
                    {
                        seriesName: 'Activité',
                        // Axis configuration...
                    }
                ],
                // Other chart options...
            },
            datasets: [{
                data : [],
                name : ''  // Needs to match 'seriesName' of y-axis
            }],
        };
    },
async mounted() {
            try {
                const transformedDataArray = await this.getAllDataHistorical();

                if (this.$refs.lineChart1) {
                    this.$refs.lineChart1.updateSeries(transformedDataArray);
                    this.$refs.areaChart1.updateSeries(transformedDataArray);
                } else {
                    console.error("Chart components are not ready.");
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Failed to load and display data:", error);
            }
        },
    methods: {
        transformData(rawData, key, tagName, prefix, color, yAxisName) {
            return {
                name: yAxisName,  // Used for axis association
                displayName: prefix + tagName,  // Real name to display
                data: rawData.map(item => [new Date(item.received_on).getTime(), item[key]]),
                color: color
            };
        },
        // Additional methods...
    }
}
</script>

The issue arises because the name property of series data must match the seriesName in the y-axis config for correct y-axis association, preventing me from using more descriptive names. How can I maintain descriptive names in legends and tooltips while ensuring that series are correctly associated with their respective axes?
here is a screen of my names in legends.. while i would like it to be property displayName..

So my question is : Is there a more efficient method to manage series names and axis association in ApexCharts without compromising on the functionality of descriptive names in the UI?

Try Changing series object format,
series: [
            {
                name: 'Session Duration',
                data: [45, 52, 38, 24, 33, 26, 21, 20, 6, 8, 15, 10]
            },
            {
                name: 'Page Views',
                data: [35, 41, 62, 42, 13, 18, 29, 37, 36, 51, 32, 35]
            },
            {
                name: 'Total Visits',
                data: [87, 57, 74, 99, 75, 38, 62, 47, 82, 56, 45, 47]
            }
        ],


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
